# SSRS Report Builder - Align/Shift Stepped Line Chart with Bar Chart

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

in SSRS Report Builder is it possible to move the stepped line chart to align perfectly on top of the bar chart below? E.g. Shift a little left.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that's not really how the Stepped Line Chart is supposed to work. The points it connects are in the center of each bar as it is supposed to be. There might be a way of manipulating your data so you achieve the look as you explained it, but this will be very complicated and far-fetched. I strongly discourage  what you're trying to do and would leave it as-is because this is how it's supposed to look and it might even cause confusion when changed.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question but what you want to achieve can be possible.

I assume your values along the X axis are dates (and if not, they could be).  All you need to do is offset the Stepped Line series to be 15 days less than the Stacked Column series.

This can be set using under Series Properties -> Series Data -> Category Field, and set the expression to be

```
=dateadd("d", -15, Fields!Expiry_Date.Value)
```

Where `Expiry_Date` is the name of the field used for the X-axis (Or the Category Group in the Chart Data window).

This method will render a chart as shown, with the Stepped Line lined up with the Stacked Column

[image]